# Using snprintf to avoid buffer overruns

Tags: c, printf

I am using `snprintf` like this to avoid a buffer overrun:

```
char err_msg[32] = {0};
snprintf(err_msg, sizeof(err_msg) - 1, "[ ST_ENGINE_FAILED ]");
```

I added the `-1` to reserve space for the null terminator in case the string is more than 32 bytes long.

Am I correct in my thinking?

Platform:

- GCC 4.4.1
- C99

Comment: Side note: GCC doesn't support C99: http://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html

Comment: Are you aware, though, of a modern environment where the gcc and standard library combo doesn't include `snprintf`?

Comment: When I was using MinGW one or two years ago, it actually called Microsoft's `_snprintf()`, which doesn't behave like the standard `snprintf()` (I think it doesn't always nul-terminate the string).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As others have said, you do not need the -1 in this case.  If the array is fixed size, I would use `strncpy` instead.  It was made for copying strings - `sprintf` was made for doing difficult formatting.  However, if the size of the array is unknown or you are trying to determine how much storage is necessary for a formatted string.  This is what I really like about the Standard specified version of `snprintf`:

```
char* get_error_message(char const *msg) {
    size_t needed = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s: %s (%d)", msg, strerror(errno), errno);
    char  *buffer = malloc(needed+1);
    sprintf(buffer, "%s: %s (%d)", msg, strerror(errno), errno);
    return buffer;
}
```

Combine this feature with `va_copy` and you can create very safe formatted string operations.

Comment: Don't use strncpy() if there string might be too big to fit into the target; strncpy() does **NOT** null-terminate what it copies if it is too long.  Further, it always copies N characters - even if the source is 1 byte and the target is 1 megabyte.

Comment: @Jonathan: Nope. while you are right that strncpy does not terminate with \0 it *does* stop if it does find a string terminator in the source string.

Comment: For fixed length buffers, I usually use `strncpy(dest, src, sizeof(dest)); dest[sizeof(dest)-1] = '\0';` That guarantees NULL termination and is just less hassle than `snprintf` not to mention that a lot of people use `snprintf(dest, sizeof(dest), src);` instead and are very surprised when their programs crash arbitrarily.

Comment: @JoãoPortela - what happens if src contains formatting codes? It crashes arbitrarily.

Comment: @IanGoldby you are correct. `snprintf(dest, sizeof(dest), "%s", src);` would work but it makes more sense to just use `strncpy` when you don't need formatting.

Comment: This code has a bug:  "Upon successful completion, the snprintf() function shall return the number of bytes that would be written to s had n been sufficiently large excluding the terminating null byte."  Thus you have to allocate an additional byte for the terminating null.

Comment: @JeremySalwen - thanks for catching that... that's what I get for writing Java =)

Comment: `snprintf(buffer, needed, …` is still a bug. You only allow snprintf to write `needed` bytes, but it needs to write `buffer+1` of them including the terminating `'\0'`, therefore you are forcing it to cut the contents short and to write the `'\0'` where the last character of contents should have been. It's a shame because you reserved room for the `'\0'` in your buffer. You just forbade `snprintf` to use it.

Comment: You could simply use `sprintf(buffer, …`, since you have reserved `buffer` of the exact right size. That would avoid this bug.

Comment: @PascalCuoq very good point.... not sure how I missed this one or how it hasn't been noticed for four and a half years

Answer (score 14):

You don't need the -1, as the reference states:

> The functions snprintf() and
>   vsnprintf() do not write more than
>   size bytes (including the trailing
>   '\0').

Note the "including the trailing '\0'" part

Answer (score 10):

No need for -1. C99 `snprintf` *always* zero-terminates. Size argument specifies the size of output buffer *including* zero terminator. The code, thus, becomes

```
char err_msg[32];
int ret = snprintf(err_msg, sizeof err_msg, "[ ST_ENGINE_FAILED ]");
```

`ret` contains actual number of characters printed (*excluding* zero terminator).

However, do not confuse with Microsoft's [`_snprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93%28VS.71%29.aspx) (pre-C99), which does **not** null-terminate, and, for that matter, has completely different behaviour (e.g. returning `-1` instead of would-be printed length in case if buffer is not big enough). If using `_snprintf`, you should be using the same code as in your question.

Answer (score 3):

According to [`snprintf(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf):

> The functions `snprintf()` and `vsnprintf()` do not write more than `size` bytes (including the trailing `'\0'`).

Answer (score 0):

For the example given, you should be doing this instead:

```
char err_msg[32];
strncpy(err_msg, "[ ST_ENGINE_FAILED ]", sizeof(err_msg));
err_msg[sizeof(err_msg) - 1] = '\0';
```

or even better:

```
char err_msg[32] = "[ ST_ENGINE_FAILED ]";
```

Comment: As noted in a comment to another answer: Don't use strncpy() if there string might be too big to fit into the target; strncpy() does NOT null-terminate what it copies if it is too long. Further, it always copies N characters - even if the source is 1 byte and the target is 1 megabyte.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, your description of how many bytes `strncpy()` is incorrect. "At most n bytes of src are copied." I've adjusted the example to fix the null-termination.

Comment: @anacrolix: your example does not guarantee NULL termination. It does guarantee that `strncpy()` will never overwrite the last character in the buffer. You have to explicitly do `err_msg[sizeof(err_msg)-1] = '\0';` to get termination.

Answer (score -1):

sizeof will return the number of bytes the datatype will use in memory, not the length of the string. E.g. sizeof(int) returns '4' bytes on a 32-bit system (well, depending on the implementation I guess). Since you use a constant in your array, you can happily pass that to the printf.

Comment: He's applying `sizeof` to the destination array, which is completely correct.

Comment: 32 is correct. In that case he does not want the size of the string  (which is given by strlen) he wants the `err_msg` buffer capacity (to guarantee it will not write past its end).