# sprintf() with automatic memory allocation?

Tags: c, malloc, printf

I'm searching for a `sprintf()`-like implementation of a function that automatically allocates required memory. So I want to say

```
char *my_str = dynamic_sprintf("Hello %s, this is a %.*s nice %05d string", a, b, c, d);
```

and `my_str` receives the address of an allocated block of memory that holds the result of this `sprintf()`.

In another forum, I read that this can be solved like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char    *ret;
    char    *a = "Hello";
    char    *b = "World";
    int     c = 123;

    int     numbytes;

    numbytes = sprintf((char *)NULL, "%s %d %s!", a, c, b);
    printf("numbytes = %d", numbytes);

    ret = (char *)malloc((numbytes + 1) * sizeof(char));
    sprintf(ret, "%s %d %s!", a, c, b);

    printf("ret = >%s<\n", ret);
    free(ret);

    return 0;
}
```

But this immediately results in a segfault when the `sprintf()` with the null pointer is invoked.

So any idea, solution or tips? A small implementation of a `sprintf()`-like parser that is placed in the public domain would already be enough, then I could get it myself done.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Whoever gave you that advice probably meant you should use `snprintf`, not `sprintf`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using snprintf to avoid buffer overruns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775403/using-snprintf-to-avoid-buffer-overruns)

Answer (score 53):

Here is the original answer [from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775403/using-snprintf-to-avoid-buffer-overruns). As others have mentioned, you need `snprintf` not `sprintf`. Make sure the second argument to `snprintf` is `zero`. That will prevent `snprintf` from writing to the `NULL` string that is the first argument.

The second argument is needed because it tells `snprintf` that enough space is not available to write to the output buffer. When enough space is not available `snprintf` returns the number of bytes it would have written, had enough space been available.

Reproducing the code from that link here ...

```
char* get_error_message(char const *msg) {
    size_t needed = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s: %s (%d)", msg, strerror(errno), errno) + 1;
    char  *buffer = malloc(needed);
    sprintf(buffer, "%s: %s (%d)", msg, strerror(errno), errno);
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add 1 to `needed` to account for the terminating null character?

Comment: Didn't spot the +1 at the end of the first line at first (it was outside the visible area): `size_t needed = snprintf(...) + 1;`

Comment: I was a little worried about whether passing NULL here invoked undefined behaviour, so I checked, and can confirm it's explicitly allowed by the C standard - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57646312/1709587.

Comment: Technically, this code is unsafe because `errno` could change between the call to `snprintf` and the call to `sprintf`, which is not protected against buffer overflow. You should use `snprintf` for both calls and you should save `errno` to a local variable before the first call.

Answer (score 37):

GNU and BSD have [asprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf) and `vasprintf` that are designed to do just that for you. It will figure out how to allocate the memory for you and will return null on any memory allocation error.

`asprintf` does the right thing with respect to allocating strings -- it first measures the size, then it tries to allocate with `malloc`. Failing that, it returns null. Unless you have your own memory allocation system that precludes the use of `malloc`, `asprintf` is the best tool for the job.

The code would look like:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char*   ret;
    char*   a = "Hello";
    char*   b = "World";
    int     c = 123;

    int err = asprintf(&ret, "%s %d %s!", a, c, b );
    if (err == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in asprintf\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("ret = >%s<\n", ret);
    free(ret);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: asprintf() would be the function of my choice - but unfortunatelly, its non standard and not portable - bad!

Comment: @the-shamen - what you are asking for is by definition non standard and not portable. Get the source for `asprintf` and pull it into your project if you need to, or reimplement it independently.

Comment: I have not heard of an `asprintf()` that returns a pointer. The one that comes with GNU and BSD (and provided by gnulib and libstrl) has the same return value as the equivalent `printf()` call and takes a pointer to a pointer as the first argument. So, `char *s; int ret = asprintf(&s, "%s %d %s!", a, c, b);` with error on `ret == -1`. Just wondering, what systems/libraries provide an `asprintf()` which returns a pointer like in this answer?

Answer (score 20):

If you can live with GNU/BSD extentions, the question is already answered. You can use `asprintf()` (and `vasprintf()` for building wrapper functions) and be done.

But `snprintf()` and `vsnprintf()` are mandated by POSIX, according to the manpage, and the latter can be used to build up your own simple version of `asprintf()` and `vasprintf()`.

```
int
vasprintf(char **strp, const char *fmt, va_list ap)
{
    va_list ap1;
    int len;
    char *buffer;
    int res;

    va_copy(ap1, ap);
    len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, ap1);

    if (len < 0)
        return len;

    va_end(ap1);
    buffer = malloc(len + 1);

    if (!buffer)
        return -1;

    res = vsnprintf(buffer, len + 1, fmt, ap);

    if (res < 0)
        free(buffer);
    else
        *strp = buffer;

    return res;
}

int
asprintf(char **strp, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int error;
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    error = vasprintf(strp, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);

    return error;
}
```

You can do some preprocessor magic and use your versions of functions only on systems that don't support them.

Comment: You can only pass `va_list` variable to one function. To use `vsnprintf()` twice as you do in `vasprintf()` you should use `va_copy()`.

Comment: It will be if you add `va_end(ap1)` before return from `vasprintf()` (e.g. right after a call to `vsnprintf()`).

Comment: you forgot to set the strp in the end of vasprintf

Comment: There is some error handling in the code (it handles failure of `calloc`) but it still blows up if `vsnprintf` were to fail: the size calculation would wrap around if less than -1 is returned as error code for the first `vsnprintf`. If the second invocation of `vsnprintf` fails, the buffer is leaked.

Comment: @user2421739 I fixed that, since this answer is quite old.

Answer (score 11):

1. If possible, use [`snprintf`](http://libslack.org/manpages/snprintf.3.html) -- it gives an easy way to measure the size of data that would be produced so you can allocate space.
2. If you **really** can't do that, another possibility is printing to a temporary file with `fprintf` to get the size, allocate the memory, and then use sprintf. `snprintf` is *definitely* the preferred method though.

Answer (score 6):

The [GLib](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/GLib) library provides a [`g_strdup_printf`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strdup-printf) function that does exactly what you want, if linking against GLib is an option.  From the documentation:

> Similar to the standard C `sprintf()`
>   function but safer, since it
>   calculates the maximum space required
>   and allocates memory to hold the
>   result. The returned string should be
>   freed with `g_free()` when no longer
>   needed.

Comment: Hello, thanks! But this is only glibc, I need a platform-independent solution. So maybe its better to do this by myself?

Comment: GLib (the base of GTK+), not GNU C Library (glibc). But it's equivalent to glibc's asprintf.

Comment: glib is platform independant

Answer (score 3):

POSIX.1 (aka IEEE 1003.1-2008) provides open_memstream:

```
char *ptr;
size_t size;
FILE *f = open_memstream(&ptr, &size);
fprintf(f, "lots of stuff here\n");
fclose(f);
write(1, ptr, size); /* for example */
free(ptr);
```

open_memstream(3) is available on at least Linux and macOS and has been for some years.   The converse of open_memstream(3) is fmemopen(3) which makes the contents of a buffer available for reading.

If you just want a single sprintf(3) then the widely-implemented but non-standard asprintf(3) might be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*  casprintf print to allocated or reallocated string

char *aux = NULL;
casprintf(&aux,"first line\n");
casprintf(&aux,"seconde line\n");
printf(aux);
free(aux);
*/
int vcasprintf(char **strp,const char *fmt,va_list ap)
{
  int ret;
  char *strp1;
  char *result;
  if (*strp==NULL)
     return vasprintf(strp,fmt,ap);

  ret=vasprintf(&strp1,fmt,ap); // ret = strlen(strp1) or -1
  if (ret == -1 ) return ret;
  if (ret==0) {free(strp1);return strlen(*strp);}

  size_t len = strlen(*strp);
  *strp=realloc(*strp,len + ret +1);
  memcpy((*strp)+len,strp1,ret+1);
  free(strp1);
  return(len+ret);
}

int casprintf(char **strp, const char *fmt, ...)
{
 int ret;
 va_list ap;
 va_start(ap,fmt);
 ret =vcasprintf(strp,fmt,ap);
 va_end(ap);
 return(ret);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context around it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.

Answer (score 0):

My version (v3) of https://stackoverflow.com/a/10388547/666907 – a bit more universal [note I'm a C++ noob, use at your own risk :P]:

```cpp
#include <cstdarg>

char* myFormat(const char* const format...) {
  // `vsnprintf()` changes `va_list`'s state, so using it after that is UB.
  // We need the args twice, so it is safer to just get two copies.
  va_list args1;
  va_list args2;
  va_start(args1, format);
  va_start(args2, format);

  size_t needed = 1 + vsnprintf(nullptr, 0, format, args1);

  // they say to cast in C++, so I cast…
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/5099675/666907
  char* buffer = (char*) malloc(needed);

  vsnprintf(buffer, needed, format, args2);

  va_end(args1);
  va_end(args2);

  return buffer;
}

char* formatted = myFormat("Foo %s: %d", "bar", 456);
Serial.println(formatted); // Foo bar: 456

free(formatted); // remember to free or u will have a memory leak!
```

Comment: This does not work because you use `args` twice and do not use `va_end()`. You must use `va_copy` or `va_start()` and `va_end()` twice. Furthermore, using `vsprintf` is risky. Why not use `vsnprintf` twice and be safe?

Comment: "This does not work"

Well, it does work, at least for my `Foo bar: 456` example and other examples I tested it on.

"You must use va_copy or va_start() and va_end() twice."

I'm noob, I just copy–pasted some code, modified is as a blind monkey, and it somehow worked xD

"Furthermore, using vsprintf is risky. Why not use vsnprintf twice and be safe?"

IDK. The example I modified used snprintf and sprintf. I changed them to "v" versions for easy args. It was suggested to use snprintf twice, but I'm noob.

Can you modify it better? Please do, I will gladly use a better version :)

Comment: @chqrlie Well, I've learnt a bit more of C++ to now understand what you meant :D I just updated the example with UB and memory leak fixed ;-)