# Determining sprintf buffer size - what's the standard?

Tags: c, int, printf

When converting an int like so:

```
char a[256];
sprintf(a, "%d", 132);
```

what's the best way to determine how large *a* should be? I assume manually setting it is fine (as I've seen it used everywhere), but how large should it be? What's the largest int value possible on a 32 bit system, and is there some tricky way of determining that on the fly?

Comment: Of course, if using C++ is an option instead then you can just use std::string and std::stringstream to accomplish what you want without even thinking about memory requirements. But that really depends. I know that the question is for C but maybe this might be useful anyway.

Comment: @Robert: if using Python is an option instead, then you can use `str` ;-p

Comment: @Steve I see your point, just wanted to see if the poster had just jumped onto C when they did not have to.

Comment: @Robert: It's for a uni assignment. I hated C prior to this unit. Now I love the simplicity. It's unforgiving, but very satisfying, with a big learning curve given I usually dabble in Python/managed langs.

Comment: @Dominic Don't get me wrong. I love C because it lets you get really close to the computer but there is a time and a place for C development. It is excellent for teaching purposes and everyone should know it if they want to be a Computer Scientist. However, now I only use it now when I want to do microcontroller development. I would argue that if you are having to think about this sort of issue then it is the wrong tool for the job. If I were you, for a uni assignment, take the path that ends up with the least bugs, so make it bigger than you need and just dont worry; premature optimisation.

Comment: Oh BTW, if you want to know the maximum size of an int then: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/climits/. That is present in C and C++.

Comment: @Robert: I would argye that if you are having to think about this sort of issue, no language other than C or assembly could possibly meet your requirements. Any other language will have monstrous difficult-to-predict stack usage, heap fragmentation, etc.

Comment: @Robert. Not sure how CS units are in the US, but in Aus, we are given very strict requirements. The whole unit is C based, so we must use C.

Comment: In the GNU world you have `asprintf`, which will internally `malloc` the needed amount of memory.

Comment: @utopianheaven This is a revelation! Why didn't I know about this before? :D

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774417/sprintf-with-automatic-memory-allocation

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The max possible number of bits in an int is `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int)`, and a decimal digit is "worth" at least 3 bits, so a loose upper bound on the space required for an arbitrary `int` is `(CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) / 3) + 3`. That +3 is one for the fact that we rounded down when dividing, one for the sign, one for the nul terminator.

If by "on a 32 bit system" you mean that you know `int` is 32 bits, then you need 12 bytes. 10 for the digits, one for the sign, one for the nul terminator.

In your specific case, where the int to be converted is `132`, you need 4 bytes. Badum, tish.

Where fixed-size buffers can be used with a reasonable bound, they are the simpler option. I not-so-humbly submit that the bound above is reasonable (13 bytes instead of 12 for 32 bit `int`, and 23 bytes instead of 21 for 64 bit `int`). But for difficult cases, in C99 you could just call `snprintf` to get the size, then `malloc` that much. That's overkill for such a simple case as this.

Comment: Using `malloc` for this is ridiculous. It overcomplicates your code by adding a failure case you have to check -- and what do you do if it fails?!? Simply use a correctly sized buffer like you explained how to do.

Comment: @R. Very well, I will expand upon my existing, "a bit overkill for such a simple case as this".

Comment: @R: Using malloc is not ridiculous if the person writing the code is interested in learning or knowing the underpinnings of the language itself.  Telling people to just use std::string because all the hard work has already done is ignorant to this point; i.e. wanting to know how things work under the hood so to speak.  Maybe the original poster wants to know how std::string does what it does?

Comment: @Eric: this question is about C, nothing to do with `std::string`.

Comment: This is dangerous - a classic potential buffer overrun scenario. The exact output of the `printf` family of functions depends on the locale. For example, a locale may set the 'thousands' separator.

Comment: @Brett: you had me going for a minute there, but of course `%d` doesn't use the thousands separator. `%'d` would, but that's not the question.

Comment: @SteveJessop - you're right about the thousands separator - I completely missed that - but I think the broader point about locale-dependent output still stands. I *want* to be wrong about this though. It's hard to get a complete overview of where locale settings can affect format specifiers.

Comment: @BrettHale: the lesson I'm taking away is that it isn't simple to determine whether you have a simple case or not :-) In some ways that could be the C programmer's motto. I'm sure it was obvious to me at the time I wrote the answer that locale wasn't relevant, but it wasn't until I'd edited the answer to mention locale, then looked back up the question and spotted the format was just `%d`, that I realised it *was* simple after all.

Comment: OK, but if we extend this conversation to cover the wide character implementation of sprintf, swprintf, the math for the malloc is further complicated. Since malloc allocates bytes, while snprintf counts characters, the allocation must be doubled for wide characters. This is such an issue that I've reduced it to a set of macros.

Comment: Reading the question, it's asking how to determine how big the buffer needs to be. It's providing an example using a particular format string and value but what if the format string has `%s`es in it and the string args can be several k each?

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: I suggest asking another question if you want to know about calculating other upper limits statically. I've already said in the answer how to do it dynamically -- call `snprintf` to get the size actually needed for the args you have. That works just as well for string args as it does for the questioner's `int`.

Answer (score 110):

Some here are arguing that this approach is overkill, and for converting ints to strings I might be more inclined to agree. But when a reasonable bound for string size cannot be found, I have seen this approach used and have used it myself.

```
int size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", 132);
char * a = malloc(size + 1);
sprintf(a, "%d", 132);
```

I'll break down what's going on here.

1. On the first line, we want to determine how many characters we need. The first 2 arguments to `snprintf` tell it that I want to write 0 characters of the result to `NULL`. When we do this, `snprintf` won't actually write any characters anywhere, it will simply return the number of characters that would have been written. This is what we wanted.
2. On the second line, we are dynamically allocating memory to a `char` pointer. Make sure and add 1 to the required size (for the trailing `\0` terminating character).
3. Now that there is enough memory allocated to the `char` pointer, we can safely use `sprintf` to write the integer to the `char` pointer.

Of course you can make it more concise if you want.

```
char * a = malloc(snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", 132) + 1);
sprintf(a, "%d", 132);
```

Unless this is a "quick and dirty" program, you always want to make sure to free the memory you called with `malloc`. This is where the dynamic approach gets complicated with C. However, IMHO, if you don't want to be allocating huge `char` pointers when most of the time you will only be using a very small portion of them, then I don't think this is bad approach.

Comment: Actually, you could often just use `alloca` instead of `malloc`. And if the resulting code is still too bloaty, make a macro for it.

Comment: How portable is `alloca`? It certainly isn't ANSI C.

Comment: Surely the portable C99 alternative to alloca is just to use a variable-length array? `int size = ...; char a[size+1]; sprintf(...`?

Comment: Don't forget to handle the case where malloc() returns NULL, unless you don't care if your program crashes or is insecure.  This is especially true if the size depends on input from outside the program.

Comment: Definitely +1, I don't get why this is not the accepted answer. It's exactly what the man page explains.

Answer (score 21):

It's possible to make Daniel Standage's solution work for any number of arguments by using [vsnprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vsnprintf/) which is in C++11/C99.

```c
int bufferSize(const char* format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    int result = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, args);
    va_end(args);
    return result + 1; // safe byte for \0
}
```

As specified in [c99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), section 7.19.6.12 :

> The vsnprintf function returns the number of characters that would
>   have  been written had n been  sufficiently  large,  not  counting 
>   the  terminating  null  character, or a negative value if an
>   encoding error occurred.

Comment: It`s pure C99 to.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't even notice. Updated my answer.

Comment: `_vscprintf` is better solution. Look at - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9369242/987850

Comment: _vscprintf is microsoft only.

Answer (score 7):

I see this conversation is a couple of years old, but I found it while trying to find an answer for MS VC++ where snprintf cannot be used to find the size.  I'll post the answer I finally found in case it helps anyone else:

VC++ has the function [`_scprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t32cf9tb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) specifically to find the number of characters needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you're printing a simple integer, and nothing else, there's a much simpler way to determine output buffer size. At least computationally simpler, the code is a little obtuse:

```
char *text;
text = malloc(val ? (int)log10((double)abs(val)) + (val < 0) + 2 : 2);
```

log10(value) returns the number of digits (minus one) required to store a positive nonzero value in base 10. It goes a little off the rails for numbers less than one, so we specify abs(), and code special logic for zero (the ternary operator, test ? truecase : falsecase). Add one for the space to store the sign of a negative number (val < 0), one to make up the difference from log10, and another one for the null terminator (for a grand total of 2), and you've just calculated the exact amount of storage space required for a given number, without calling snprintf() or equivalents *twice* to get the job done. Plus it uses less memory, generally, than the INT_MAX will require.

If you need to print a lot of numbers very quickly, though, do bother allocating the INT_MAX buffer and then printing to that repeatedly instead. Less memory thrashing is better.

Also note that you may not actually need the (double) as opposed to a (float). I didn't bother checking. Casting back and forth like that may also be a problem. YMMV on all that. Works great for me, though.

Comment: Let us say that your integer is `INT_MIN`. Then `abs(val)` is `INT_MIN`, `log10` applied to it returns NaN, and converting NaN to `int` is undefined behavior. Besides, if you are printing 64-bit integers, the largest of them are not representable exactly as `double`.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq -- Interesting quirk, thanks for that. I guess the solution isn't really complete without checking if we're trying to allocate storage for the string representation of INT_MIN, but I'm feeling lazy, so I'll leave that as an exercise for anyone who actually cares to do it.

-- P.S. "undefined behavior" is an understatement. In GCC, printf("%d\n", (int)log10((double)abs(-2147483647 - 1))); spits out "-2147483648" instead of the expected "9" -- how odd.

Answer (score 1):

First off, sprintf is the devil. If anything, use snprintf, or else you risk trashing memory and crashing your app.

As for the buffer size, it's like all other buffers - as small as possible, as big as necessary. In your case, you have a signed integer, so take the largest possible size, and feel free to add a little bit of safety padding. There is no "standard size".

It's also not dependent on what system you're running on. If you define the buffer on the stack (like in your example), it depends on the size of the stack. If you created the thread yourself, then you determined the stack size yourself, so you know the limits. If you are going to expect recursion or a deep stack trace, then you need to extra careful as well.

Comment: Thank you. snprintf it is then.

Comment: There is no danger to using `sprintf` with a correctly sized buffer. For numeric output, sizing the buffer is easy. See Steve's answer.

Comment: @R.. Assuming another thread doesn't clobber some of the input behind your back...

Comment: @tc.: In that case `snprintf` would not help you. Unsynchronized access to data is **always** undefined behavior. It's equally possible that `snprintf` could overflow if the string size changes out from under it.

Comment: @R.. While it's not *guaranteed* to help you, I can think of obvious situations and implementations where `snprintf()` would at least stop it from crashing.

Comment: Not necessarily. `snprintf` might very well have a TOCTOU race, first checking `strlen` then doing `strcpy` or similar. Unless you've read the implementation source, you don't know. If your program is so broken that it's doing unsynchronized data access (one of the worst forms of UB because it "seems to work" "most of the time") then using `snprintf` here is not going to make a dent in your program's brokenness.

Answer (score 1):

Its good that you are worried about buffer size. To apply that thought in code, I would use [snprintf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#sprintf)

```
snprintf( a, 256, "%d", 132 );
```

or

```
snprintf( a, sizeof( a ), "%d", 132 );  // when a is array, not pointer
```

Comment: `snprintf` only solves half the problem. If you're not sure your buffer is big enough, you need to use `snprintf` to test the necessary size or make sure your code does not have bugs when the output gets truncated. Steve's answer is a lot better.