# Calculating the size of an sprintf() buffer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, printf

A (very long) while ago I regularly used the following code - then on MSVC 6 - to determine the memory needed to format a string for a function with variadic arguments:

```
void LogPrint(const char *pszFormat, ...)
{
    int          nBytes;
    char        *pszBuffer;
    va_list      args;

    va_start(args, pszFormat);
    nBytes = vsnprintf(0, 0, pszFormat, va);
    va_end(args);

    // error checking omitted for brevity
    pszBuffer = new char[nBytes + 1];

    va_start(args, pszFormat);
    vsnprintf(pszBuffer, nBytes, pszFormat, va);
    va_end();

    // ...
}
```

The obvious error you're getting in a more recent version of MSVC (I'm using 2010 now) is:

> warning C4996: 'vsnprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using vsnprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

I'm a big fan of the "treat warnings as errors" option for any C(++)-compiler, and obviously my build fails. It feels like cheating to me to simply employ `#pragma warning (disable:4996)` and get on with it.

The suggested "safer" alternative `vsnprintf_s()`, however [is doomed to return `-1`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3xd30zz.aspx) when input conditions of its "unsafe" predecessor occur.

**TL/DR:** Is there a way to implement the expected behavior of `vsnprintf()` to return the memory needed to fulfil its task using the new, safer variants of it?

---

**EDIT:** simply defining `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` won't cut it; there's a lot of `strcpy()` flying around, too. The new variant of which isn't broken, so I'd like to still see these.

Comment: `vsprintf_s` is not only m$ only (and thus unportable), it is said by many people that its sole purpose to exist is to tighten your vendor lock-in, so have you thought about disabling the suggestion to replace all standard calls by _s variants?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: C11 contains the `_s` functions as recommendations in the optional Appendix K.

Comment: Yeah. I have. But as I said, it feels like cheating to me. After all - apart from vendor-locking software - someone must have thought of `vsnprintf()`'s nifty feature *before* making it unavailable?

Comment: The rest of the warning, which you did not include in your question, is a #define you can set to avoid this vendor-specific warning. I suppose that's no different than the pragma you posit, but either method should be fine.

Comment: According to C99, you can pass size zero and a null pointer to `(v)snprintf` and obtain the required output size as the return value.

Comment: Have you considered using a type-safe templated printf() variant or iostreams-based code instead? That will give you more safety than vsnprintf_s can, and surely the point should be to fix the problem that the warning indicates rather than just tweaking the code to avoid the warning.

Comment: @KerrekSB ...which is why the above code worked then. Its allegedely "safer" successor doesn't, however.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining sprintf buffer size - what's the standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919995/determining-sprintf-buffer-size-whats-the-standard)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The function you want to look at is [`_vscprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w05tbk72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), which *"returns the number of characters that would be generated if the string pointed to by the list of arguments was printed or sent to a file or buffer using the specified formatting codes"*. There's a widechar variant (`_vscwprintf`) as well.