# How does snprintf alignment bytes

Tags: c, int, printf

Following the answer of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919995/determining-sprintf-buffer-size-whats-the-standard), I wanted to see how many bytes a snprintf uses. The following code

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d:%llx:%d:%llx:%llx:%llx", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
    printf("%d\n", snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d:%llx:%d:%llx:%llx:", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
    printf("%d\n", snprintf(NULL, 0, "%llx", 0));
    return 0;
}
```

returns

```
22
10
1
```

I do not understand how the %llx at the end of other data printed can use 12 bytes while it uses only 1 byte if it is used alone. Does snprintf do any byte alignment?

Comment: @Stargateur UB is U.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Indeed, never mind, I always forget that C don't infer type in variadic function.

Comment: Undefined behaviour, schmundefined schmehaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a bug. The `%llx` format specifier is only for `long long`s. Try:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d:%llx:%d:%llx:%llx:%llx", 0, 0LL, 0LL, 0LL, 0LL, 0LL));
    printf("%d\n", snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d:%llx:%d:%llx:%llx:", 0, 0LL, 0LL, 0LL, 0LL));
    printf("%d\n", snprintf(NULL, 0, "%llx", 0LL));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Technically `unsigned long long`, so it should be `0ull`.

Comment: If we do not have ull, how does C compile it? Does it think this is an undefined code?