get length of formatted string before format with security enhancements
I want to convert my code from "unsecure" version to "secure" to avoid an error and the define:
int l = sprintf(NULL, "%.*f", precision, newVal);
char* msg = (char*)malloc(l + 1);
sprintf(msg, "%.*f", precision, newVal);


error C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

My problem is if I write this:
int l = sprintf_s(NULL, 0, "%.*f", precision, newVal);
char* msg = (char*)malloc(l + 1);
sprintf_s(msg, l, "%.*f", precision, newVal);

An exception is fired:

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFFEA83924C (ucrtbased.dll) in WinTests.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.

So, how is it supposed to be done?

If you're that interested in 'security' why are you still using 'C' style varargs functions for this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919995/determining-sprintf-buffer-size-whats-the-standard

I am curious , To go on my work I changed my code with msg = std::format("{0:.{1}f}", newVal, precision)

just use C++20 std::format instead using old C-API.

Your "insecure" version doesn't work either (program return value of 3221226505 is in fact 0xC0000409 thrown by invalid parameter handler). NULL is not a valid first argument for sprintf

You can use _scprintf to compute how large a buffer you would need. It exists specifically for this purpose.

Use std::snprintf passing in a nullptr for the buffer to calculate the buffer length, which includes the '\0' terminator.  But better to use std::ostringstream or std::format.

No matter how much MS might like you to think so, switching from C standard library functions to Microsoft _s counterparts does not convert code from unsecure to secure.  Code using functions such as sprintf() is not for that reason inherently insecure, and code using functions such as sprintf_s() is not for that reason inherently secure.  Approximately the same amount of effort that goes into using the _s functions correctly is also sufficient to ensure that the standard functions are used safely.
