# Expected behaviour when null pointer given to snprintf

Tags: c++, c, pointers, printf

What is the expected behaviour for this code snippet?

```
char * aNullPointer = 0;
snprintf (res, 128, "Testing %s null pointer",aNullPointer);
```

Note that I am deliberately trying to get it to de-reference my null pointer `aNullPointer`.

Behaviour 1) `res` points to a string "Testing (null) null pointer"

Behaviour 2) Seg Fault

It seems I get differing behaviours depending on my platform. Some `snprintf` implementations perform a sanity check, whereas others do not.

What is the most common behaviour?

Comment: There is no expected behaviour. The behaviour is undefined.

Comment: I once tried this, and pancakes appeared in the CD slot.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Better than nasal demons I suppose

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, compiler and platform! I want it!

Comment: The expected behavior is that the Sun turns green and the Earth stops rotating. i.e. it is undefined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's undefined behavior - there's nothing to expect. The fact that some implementations check for `NULL` and replace it with "nil" or "null" is just a nicety, you can't rely on it at all.

Comment: I guess I was just thinking that snprintf is supposed to be a `safer` version so it might sanity check for nulls. But of course you are right!

Answer (score 4):

One caveat to the other answers here: it *is* permissible to pass a null pointer as the first argument to `snprintf` *if* the second argument (specifying the number of bytes to write) is zero.

From the C11 standard (emphasis mine):

> The `snprintf` function is equivalent to `fprintf`, except that the output is written into an array (specified by argument `s`) rather than to a stream. **If `n` is zero, nothing is written, and s may be a null pointer.**

This can be useful to first find out how many bytes `snprintf` wants to write in order to allocate a buffer of that size to write to with a second call to `snprintf`, as shown at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10388547/1709587.

If `n` is nonzero, however, the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Undefined behaviour. Don't do it.

glibc will use `(null)` when passing a NULL pointer to `%s` though, but don't rely on this feature!

Answer (score 1):

There is in a sense no expected behavior. In fact, it is explicitly stated in the standard that the behaviour is undefined in quite a wide sense: it can work, it can segfault, it can format your harddrive etc. You should check for `NULL` pointers yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If we regard to the [Opengroup specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html), it seems that there's no defined behaviour for this case:

> The argument shall be a pointer to an array of char. Bytes from the array shall be
>   written up to (but not including) any terminating null byte. If the precision is
>   specified, no more than that many bytes shall be written. If the precision is not
>   specified or is greater than the size of the array, the application shall ensure that the 
>   array contains a null byte.