# find the length of a formatted string in C

Tags: c, strlen

I have below function in my application:

```
 void func(char *file, int line)
 {
    char stmt[150];
    sprintf(stmt, "Failed in file %s, at line number %d", file, line);
 }
```

Here I am taking char array of 150 bytes(rough guess), instead I need to find the length of the string that I gave in sprintf() and take the array of that size.

Pls suggest me if such facility in C to find the length of a formatted string.
Thanks !

Comment: If you do not have an upper bound for the length of `file`, you need to allocate the necessary amount of memory by using `malloc()`.

Comment: `int length = snprintf(NULL, 0, "Failed in file %s, at line number %d", file, line);`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774417/sprintf-with-automatic-memory-allocation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about `snprintf`? The function does not write more characters than given number, but returns the length of the string it would create if it had enough space.

```
 int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "Failed in file %s, at line number %d", file, line);
```