# Unexpected behavior with sprintf

Tags: c, printf, allocation

I am writing a program and I have a very weird issue.

```
char *abs_alg *iterator *test_case;
sprintf(abs_alg, "%s/data_root/projects/PROJ-%s/proj/src/%sAbsAlgorithm.cpp", getenv(ALGATOR_ROOT), argv[2], argv[2]);
sprintf(iterator, "%s/data_root/projects/PROJ-%s/proj/src/%sTestSetIterator.cpp", getenv(ALGATOR_ROOT), argv[2], argv[2]);
sprintf(test_case, "%s/data_root/projects/PROJ-%s/proj/src/%sTestCase.cpp", getenv(ALGATOR_ROOT), argv[2], argv[2]);
```

In last row, I get runtime error:
*Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x3)*

First two sprintf function are working just fine, but this last one isn't. Also, if I change *char *test_case to char test_case[500]*, then I get error before in program in this line:

```
char *lib_dir;
sprintf(lib_dir, "%s/data_root/projects/PROJ-%s/lib/", getenv(ALGATOR_ROOT), argv[2]);
```

I am using XCode-beta 7.0.

```
g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.53.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

I've been trying to fix this all day but without success. I would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: `abs_alg`, `lib_dir` have to be pre-allocated somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sprintf` does not allocate memory for the returning string (`lib_dir` in your case).

Assuming the answer is 256 characters at most you should write:

```
char lib_dir[256];
sprintf(lib_dir, "%s/data_root/projects/PROJ-%s/lib/", getenv(ALGATOR_ROOT), argv[2]);
```

If you're not sure about the size limit, you can check out this question regarding [sprintf() with automatic memory allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774417/sprintf-with-automatic-memory-allocation).

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you! :)