# C: How to initialize a string with the result of a function?

Tags: c, arrays, string, initialization

Firstly, I'm new to C, and have only a very basic understanding of it. I haven't got my head round the whole idea of pointers and memory management yet, so I'm still approaching it from a Java mindset - so any 'pointers' in the right direction would be appreciated. (Excuse the pun)

I have a function that converts an integer of seconds into a string in the format "days:hours:minutes:seconds".

I'm trying to initialize a string by calling that function on an integer, but

```
const char * timeConvert(int secs){
    ...
    return("%d:%d:%d:%d",days,hours,minutes,seconds);
}

int main(){
    char time[11] = timeConvert(61);
    printf(time);
    return 0;
}
```

"..." is code that does the conversions into days/hours/mins/secs and is not relevant to the issue.

With this code I get an error on the line "char time[11] = timeConvert(61);" saying "error: invalid initializer"

If I remove that line and replace main with this...

```
int main()
{
    printf(timeConvert(61));
    return 0;
}
```

...The program appears to compile but crashes with a "A problem causes the program to stop working correctly" error.

Can someone tell me why these approaches do not work, and how to work around this?

I essentially want to input an integer to a function that gives me back a string in the format "days:hours:minutes:seconds" which I can then print to the console.

Comment: make the developer pass the character array as parameter and use sprintf

Comment: And pay attention to compiler warnings, which should certainly have been given for that `return` line.

Comment: You can't figure out how C strings work by guessing, you actually have to read the chapter about string handling in your C book. And before that, the chapter about arrays and pointers. Stack Overflow is not a replacement for studies.

Comment: Strings in C are `'\0'`terminated character arrays. Working with them is very different then it is in Java. I recommend you read a C book.

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774417/sprintf-with-automatic-memory-allocation

Answer (score 2):

This isn't doing what you think:

```
return("%d:%d:%d:%d",days,hours,minutes,seconds);
```

This is actually a sequence of comma operators.  The comma operator evaluates each expression in order and the whole expression has the value of the last expression.  So this is the same as:

```
return seconds;
```

Which should be throwing a compiler warning.

You also can't do this:

```
char time[11] = timeConvert(61);
```

Since `timeConvert` returns a `char *`, while `time` is an array.

You probably want to pass your array to this function which will then populate it using `sprintf`.

```
void timeConvert(char time[], int secs){
    ...
    sprintf(time,"%d:%d:%d:%d",days,hours,minutes,seconds);
}

int main(){
    // make this long enough for the NULL terminator
    // plus some extra chars in case you pass in a larger value
    char time[15];
    timeConvert(time,61);
    printf(time);
    return 0;
}
```

Also note that `time` is larger.  If `days`, `hours`, `minutes`, and `seconds` are all double digit numbers, the total length of the string is 11 characters plus 1 for the NULL terminator for a total of 12.  Defining it as `char time[11]` doesn't give you enough space, and you end up writing past the end of the array, causing undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a string out of your function you have to use `sprintf()`. See the example at the following link. With this you can format an output and store it in a string.

[C Reference sprintf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/)

Further to keep you application open for debugging purposes you can add a `scanf()` in the main or a `while(1)` as the last line before return 0 to prevent the application that it closes itself.