# Error opening physical file with _Ropen

Tags: c++, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400, ibm-ifs

I'm trying to put physical file on IFS.

So trying to open file just to guarantee its presence on source.

This is how I do it:

```
errno=0;                                                          
if ( ((pf = _Ropen(pfname, "rr, nullcap=Y")) == NULL) || (errno!=0) )
{
   printf("\nError:  Cannot open file %s\n",pfname);
   //...
}
```

However, the file not gets opened with `pf = SPP:*NULL` result

That won't be the issue, but I can't also view `errno`.
The `eval errno` gives `Syntax error occurred.` without any clue what has happened.

I'm still able to view contents of `pfname`: it looks like `'MYLIB/MYFILE'`

Absolute path was also tried:
`'/QSYS.LIB/MYLIB.LIB/MYFILE.FILE'`, without any difference - same error persists.

IBM IFS explorer clearly shows contents of `MYLIB` and there is a `MYFILE` inside this lib.

**UPD**

I've added some debug logging just to extcact error description or error code:

```
numbytes = sprintf( (char *)NULL, "%s", strerror(errno) );

ret = (char *)malloc( ( numbytes + 1 ) * sizeof( char ) );

sprintf( ret, "%s", strerror(errno) );
```

And the result of `ret` is `SPP:*NULL`.

Any ideas to try?

Comment: Maybe in the printf() you can try `printf("\nError: Cannot open file %s with errno %d\n", pfname, errno);`

Comment: Maybe read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10388547/2296441) to figure out the debugging issues you are having.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be super simple - null byte was missing so `_Ropen` can not really access the file thus no error to be passed as well.

To handle this the argument of null-terminated byte array needs to be passed from caller.
In case of rpg solution looks like `'MYFILE/MYLIB' + X'00'`