# How to show output on terminal and save to a file at the same time in C?

Tags: c, file, io

This the code I have for printing the contents to a file named output.log:

```
FILE *openFile(void)
{
    FILE *entry;
    entry = fopen("output.log", "a");
    if (entry != NULL)/*verifying whether it opened*/
    {/*printing the --- separator*/
        fprintf(entry, "---\n");/*unable to write to unopened file*/
    }
    return entry;
}

void writeFile(FILE *entry, char *category, double formerX, double 
formerY, double     latestX, double latestY)
{
    /*writing an entry to the given file, as told in the given 
    document*/
    fprintf(entry, "%4s (%7.3f, %7.3f)-(%7.3f, %7.3f) \n", category, 
    formerX, formerY, latestX, latestY);
}

/*closing the file and checking for errors*/
void closeFile(FILE *entry)
{
    if (ferror(entry))
    {
        perror("Error, can't write to the file");
    }
    fclose(entry);
}
```

I want to now print the same content (saved in output.log) on the terminal screen. How can I add this functionality?

Here is a section of output.log:

```
MOVE (  0.000,   0.000)-( 18.000,  -0.000) 
DRAW ( 18.000,  -0.000)-( 19.000,  -0.000)
DRAW ( 19.000,  -0.000)-( 20.000,  -0.000)
DRAW ( 20.000,  -0.000)-( 21.000,  -0.000)
DRAW ( 21.000,  -0.000)-( 22.000,  -0.000)
DRAW ( 22.000,  -0.000)-( 23.000,  -0.000)
DRAW ( 23.000,  -0.000)-( 25.000,  -0.000)
MOVE ( 25.000,  -0.000)-(  0.000,  -0.000)
MOVE (  0.000,  -0.000)-( -0.000,   1.000)
MOVE ( -0.000,   1.000)-( 18.000,   1.000)
DRAW ( 18.000,   1.000)-( 19.000,   1.000)
```

Comment: You could first use `sprintf` to format your data into a buffer and then output via `printf` and `fprintf`.

Comment: With shell tools you could use `tail -f output.log` on another shell or if your program only prints to `stdout` you could use `myprog | tee output.log`

Comment: @Gerhardh in that case he'll use a `malloc` correctly set, and maybe [`snprintf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774417).

Comment: @Amessihel The possible values seem very limited. A fixed size buffer should be sufficient here.

Comment: @Amessihel it worked, but my graphics are messed up, so I need to redirect the printf output to another terminal window. How can I do that? Essentially,  The log entries should be being printed to stderr.

Comment: `fprintf(stderr, ...)` You can find it with a search using the keywords `fprintf` `stderr`.

Comment: @Amessihel It still prints to the same terminal window

Comment: @BhushanOza unless you redirect the output in shell. You might try to open an another terminal device (/dev/tty*) as an additional output file, and write there, but you need specify it as a command line argument and check it at every single run as terminal ID might change.

Comment: The much easier way is preserve your output routine intact in the original form and in other terminal run `tail -fF ouput_file`. this will write all output from that file to the other terminal and save your time.

Comment: @Eir Nym . thanks for the tail -fF output.log command. Is there a way to write a program in C that automatically redirects output to another terminal without specifying any arguments?

Comment: As I wrote just before, you need specify TTY line to output every time. It's a dynamic variable and can't be done automatically in the very easy way. In most cases easiest solution beats the best one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ways to solve printing to the terminal and saving output to file

- Using `printf()`, or `fprintf(stdin, "");` to stdin, statement after `fprintf();`
- Using `system("cat output.log");`(works in linux) after writing to file.
- Using function which will print the file after writing like

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printFile(FILE *fp) {
  char line[2048];
  while (fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]s", line) == 1) {
    printf("%s\n", line);
    fgetc(fp); // OR fseek(fp, 1, 1); To throw away the new line in the input
               // buffer
  }
}
int main() {
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("a.txt", "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening the file\n");
    return 1;
  }
  printFile(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

- Using linux shell
  `./a.out | tee output.log`
  and use normal printf() statement inside your C code.