# Char array or const char* (Memory efficiency)

Tags: c++, arduino

For my use case, I need to use `const char*` strings to pass to functions, at first I used a `char` array, but I ended up to use a lot of memory.

This is my first method using a char array:

```cpp
char name[30];
sprintf(name, "Name: %s", "Ricardo");
```

This is my second and I think better method:

```cpp
const char* name; // Declare only
{
  char buf[30];
  sprintf(buf, "Name: %s", "Ricardo");
  name = buf;
}
```

In this second method, the string will contain only the memory needed.
Do you think this is the best approach?

### PS: I'm using C++ for Arduino

Comment: `name` points at garbage memory right after the assignment since `buf` has gone out of scope.  Why not just use `char const * name = "Name: Ricardo"`?

Comment: @StephenNewell this is just an example, the String `Ricardo` is unknown at compile time

Comment: This code would exhibit undefined behavior. After `buf` goes out of scope, any pointers to it's elements become invalid and can not be dereferenced - so `name` becomes unusable. The actual snippet doesn't show any usage of `name`, so by itself it is valid, but I'd assume, there would be some code accessing `name` later.

Comment: @SergeyA No, it works. I tested and works very good. Even when it goes out of scope

Comment: `the string will contain only the memory needed` No, sorry, that assessment is just invalid. This is not how the language works, sorry. `I tested and works very good.` C++ has this special thing called [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). That something "works", does not mean it's correct.

Comment: `I tested and works very good. ` this is the very definition of undefined behavior :) It appears to work, in your specific example, under specific conditions. It might work today, but will fail spectacularly tomorrow.

Comment: @SergeyA Strangely my code suddenly stopped working correctly, and I don't know why.... So, in this case what's the best approach?

Comment: `Strangely` - this is not strange at all, and should be expected with undefined behavior. Your first approach is the way to go. But you need to replace `sprintf` with `snprintf` to make sure you do not go out of array bounds.

Comment: Of course it "works", because it's the only code in your test. And of course it will bite you pretty hard if you use it in bigger program. It's really bad idea to use this code. But if you really want to shoot your own leg, do it.

Comment: Minimizing memory usage is an honorable goal, but it is like with minimizing the money usage - if you need to spend it on something you need, you have to spend it, and if you become creative with obtaining goods without spending money on them - well, it might end not so pretty for you.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you think this is the best approach?

Definitely not. The memory of `buf` is going out of scope when enclosing block `}` ends. The lifetime of `buf` ended. After that, the `name` *pointer points* to invalid memory location. Dereferencing the pointer, for example by printing the content of memory the pointer *points* to, is invalid.

> This is my first method using a char array:

And it's almost perfect. A seasoned programmer might prefer `snprintf` to protect against buffer overflow:

```
char name[30];
snprintf(name, sizeof(name), "Name: %s", "Ricardo");
```

But you are using C++ - no need to use C interfaces. If you want to *dynamically allocate* memory, use `stringstream` and such, for example:

```
std::stringstream ss;
// stringstream resizes internal buffer to accommodate input
// ie. "the string will contain only the memory needed"
ss << "Name: " << "Ricardo";
// std::string automatically frees memory in destructor
std::string name = ss.str();
```

or really, if you do not need formatting capabilities of `stringstream`, then just `std::string`:

```
std::string name = std::string() + "Name: " + "Ricardo";
```

If you want to dynamically allocate memory using C interfaces, you typically call `snprintf` twice, as shown to the answer in [sprintf() with automatic memory allocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774417/sprintf-with-automatic-memory-allocation) . If you are using newlib as standard library, [`asprintf()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) might also be available.

Comment: You missed the Arduino tag and explicit mentioning of Arduino in the question.

Comment: I'm using stringstream on my arduino. I think arduino moved to C++11-ish gcc, didn't it? Well, my last journey with arduino was with ESP82 - I used c++17 on it and arduino libraries. But surely I may be out-of-touch with the platform.