# Dynamic memory allocation of buffer for vsprintf

Tags: c, embedded, printf

I want to allocate a dynamic memory to a buffer, and I am storing the data in it through `vsprintf();`. I am creating a logging mechanism that requires the use of vsprintf and every time my data is different so I want to allocate dynamic memory to the buffer. But I don't know how I can get the size of the `format` and `va_list args`.

I have no clue from where I can start and how can I get the buffer length

Any help would be great.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. I propose to create it by using a huge buffer (large enough for the at least two different sets of data) and showing how the same call to vsprintf() gets differently sized data.

Comment: Okay sure just give me a little time I will share it with you.

Comment: Of course take your time. You have the option to delete your question, edit it for improval and when you are satisfied undelete it. That way it will only be judged when you are ready. Good luck.

Comment: Actually, I just solved the issue should I delete the question?

Comment: Either that or, even better, show your solution in an answer you create. Just make sure that all the info someone else would have needed to answer is in the question. E.g. [ask], [mre].

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774417/sprintf-with-automatic-memory-allocation answer your quesiton?

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, the link which you shared is the similar solution that I implemented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `vsprintf()` because there is no way to tell this function the size of the destination array. You should instead use `vsnprintf()` and you can compute the length of the formatted string from the return value of `vsnprintf()`.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int logstuff(const char *fmt, ...) {
    char buffer[256];
    char *str;
    int length;
    va_list args;

    /* format the message into a local buffer */
    va_start(args, fmt);
    length = vsnprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);

    if (length < 0) {
        /* encoding error */
        [...]
        return -1;
    }

    if ((unsigned)length < sizeof buffer) {
        /* message is OK, allocate a copy */
        str = strdup(buffer);
    } else {
        /* message was truncated, allocate a large enough array */
        str = malloc(length + 1U);
    }
    if (!str) {
        /* allocation error */
        [...]
        return -1;
    }
    if ((unsigned)length >= sizeof buffer) {
        /* format the message again */
        va_start(args, fmt);
        length = vsnprintf(str, length + 1U, fmt, args);
        va_end(args);
    }

    /* store the message somewhere */
    [...]

    return length;
}
```