# snprintf error. argument to sizeof is the same as destination

Tags: c, gcc, printf

gcc 4.8 give me an error when I build

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static inline void toto(char str[3])
{
    snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "XX"); 
}

int main(){
    char str[3]; 
    toto(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the gcc error

**error: argument to ‘sizeof’ in ‘snprintf’ call is the same expression as the destination; did you mean to provide an explicit length?**

Note: I m using -Wall -Werror flags which convert warning to error.

[There is something similar here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775403/using-snprintf-to-avoid-buffer-overruns)
In a comment, someone answered this

*"For fixed length buffers, I usually use strncpy(dest, src, sizeof(dest)); dest[sizeof(dest)-1] = '\0'; That guarantees NULL termination and is just less hassle than snprintf not to mention that a lot of people use snprintf(dest, sizeof(dest), src); instead and are very surprised when their programs crash arbitrarily."*

But this is wrong:
gcc 4.8 say

**"error: argument to ‘sizeof’ in ‘strncpy’ call is the same expression as the destination; did you mean to provide an explicit length? [-Werror=sizeof-pointer-memaccess]"**

[in gcc 4.8 documentation, they are talking about this issue](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/porting_to.html):
they say:

*The behavior of -Wall has changed and now includes the new warning flag -Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess. This may result in new warnings in code that compiled cleanly with previous versions of GCC.*

For example,

```
include string.h

struct A { };

int main(void) 
{
    A obj;
    A* p1 = &obj;
    A p2[10];

    memset(p1, 0, sizeof(p1)); // error
    memset(p1, 0, sizeof(*p1)); // ok, dereferenced
    memset(p2, 0, sizeof(p2)); // ok, array
    return 0;
}
```

*Gives the following diagnostic:
warning: argument to ‘sizeof’ in ‘void* memset(void*, int, size_t)’ call is the same expression as the destination; did you mean to dereference it? [-Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess]
  memset(p1, 0, sizeof(p1)); // error
                       ^
Although these warnings will not result in compilation failure, often -Wall is used in conjunction with -Werror and as a result, new warnings are turned into new errors.
To fix, either re-write to use memcpy or dereference the last argument in the offending memset call.*

Well, in their example, it's obvious the code was wrong, but in my case, with snprintf/strncpy, I dont see why, and I think it's a false positif error of gcc. Right ?

thanks for your help

Comment: Odd, the documentation for `-Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess` makes me think that it would warn if you had written `char *str` in your first example, but that it shouldn't warn for `char str[3]`.

Comment: with g++ , i didn't get any error.

Comment: With gcc 4.8.1, I couldn't reproduce the warning. Surely you are using `char str[3]` and not `char *str` ?

Comment: Yes, it's seems it may work in some case. So, I updated my post, and I provided an example which doesnt work. Just copy the code and run gcc -Wall -Werror -o test main.c, and you should got the error

Comment: I also have gcc 4.8.1, and I use debian. (I also have this error using g++)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An array decays into a pointer to the first element when you passed to a function. So what you have in

`static inline void toto(char str[3]) {..}`

is not an array but a pointer.

Hence, gcc rightly warns.

Whether you specify the size in the function parameter or not doesn't matter as:

```
static inline void toto(char str[3])
```

and

```
static inline void toto(char str[])
```

and

```
static inline void toto(char *str)
```

are all equivalent.

Read here on this: [**what is array decaying?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Answer (score 7):

test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bar(char foo[1000])
{
    printf ("sizeof foo = %d\n", (int)(sizeof foo));
}

int main ()
{
    char foo[1000];
    bar(foo);
}
```

running:

```
bash $ ./test
4
bash $
```

That's why.

Answer (score 3):

In your function definition, the parameter declaration:

```
static inline void toto(char str[3])
```

does not declare `str` as an array (C doesn't have parameters of array type). Rather, it's exactly equivalent to:

```
static inline void toto(char *str)
```

The `3` is quietly ignored.

So `sizeof(str)` has nothing to do with the number of characters the string can hold, it's simply the size of a `char*` pointer.

This results from a rule that says a parameter declared with an array type is "adjusted" to be of pointer type. This is distinct from the rule that says expressions of array type are implicitly converted (or "decay") to pointers in most contexts. The two rules work together to make code that deals with arrays seem like it's dealing with the arrays directly, when it's really working with pointers to elements of the arrays.

The relationship between C arrays and pointers is often confusing. I recommend reading section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/); it does a very good job of explaining it.

Answer (score 2):

```
static inline void toto(char str[3])
```

defines a function that can take an *array of any size*. The `3` is ignored, and `str` is treated as a pointer (try `printf("%d\n", sizeof(str))`: on my machine, it prints 8 for the size of a 64-bit pointer). The compiler is actually right in this case.

Clang gives a useful warning here:

```
test.c:6:25: warning: sizeof on array function parameter will return size of
      'char *' instead of 'char [3]' [-Wsizeof-array-argument]
    snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "XX");
```