# sizeof on pointer

Tags: c, pointers, arguments, sizeof

I was trying to compile a kernel for my HTC phone when my compiler warned about this:

```
static ssize_t mipi_dsi_3d_barrier_read(struct device *dev,
                struct device_attribute *attr,
                char *buf)
{
    return snprintf((char *)buf, sizeof(buf), "%u\n", barrier_mode);
}
```

with the message

> warning: argument to 'sizeof' in 'snprintf' call is the same
>   expression as the destination; did you mean to provide an explicit
>   length? [-Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess]
>       error, forbidden warning: mipi_novatek.c:524

I fixed a few like this already, as I understand that sizeof(buf) makes no sense, because buf is passed as an argument and therefore the compiler has no idea of the buffer size -even if you happen to pass a static buffer.

Thing is, after fixing a few like this, I am wondering if I am missing something. I downloaded the kernel from a github repository, with quite a few commits from the "original" htc kernel, and I could find these errors in both, so surely it compiled fine for others.

Am I missing or doing something wrong? I am using arm-none-eabi-gcc 4.8.2 from my ubuntu repository, instead of downloading from android.googlesource.com as advised. But regardless of the compiler, this is a bug, isn't it? Shouldn't you pass the buffer size as an extra argument?

**EDIT** Another such example in the same kernel...

```
struct msm_adsp_module *module;

...

if (!strncmp(module->name, "QCAMTASK", sizeof(module->name)))
    module_irq_cnt[1]++;
else if(!strncmp(module->name, "VFETASK", sizeof(module->name)))
    module_irq_cnt[2]++;
else if(!strncmp(module->name, "VIDEOENCTASK", sizeof(module->name)))
    module_irq_cnt[3]++;
```

where

```
struct msm_adsp_module {
    struct mutex lock;
    const char *name;
    ...
```

Comment: How did you fix this code?

Comment: Curious, why the cast in `(char *)buf`?  Ah, I see it is not your code.

Comment: Note it's not "because buf is an argument" but rather "because buf is a pointer".

Comment: @immibis Right, changed the title to make the post less confusing.

Comment: @M.M Didn't fix anything really. It is a 32 bit architecture, so I replaced `sizeof(buf)` with `4`, with the hope of having exactly the same (adjectives here) behaviour than during whatever testing this kernel had, if any. I don't see a quick proper fix. Considered `sprintf` to avoid the warning, but that could bring its own legion of issues...

Comment: OK. It might be a buffer overflow still, I guess you should check all the call sites to this function

Answer (score 2):

Oops, sorry, just missed it from this other thread, which makes the issue very clear

[snprintf error. argument to sizeof is the same as destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202368/snprintf-error-argument-to-sizeof-is-the-same-as-destination)

> in gcc 4.8 documentation, they are talking about this issue: they say:
>
> The behavior of -Wall has changed and now includes the new warning
>   flag -Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess. This may result in new warnings in
>   code that compiled cleanly with previous versions of GCC.

So I guess it surely is a bug, and others just happen to use older compilers. I just couldn't believe there was such code on production kernels...