# Issues with sprintf

Tags: c, printf

I have been trying to use sprintf to add " to the start and end of a integer, however when i use more than 10 digits the program returns the wrong number:

```
int data2 = 12345678910;
char data3[2];  
sprintf(data3,"\"%i\"", data2);  
send(data3);
```

The send function outputs the integer to the screen.
The result i am getting back is :

> "-108508098"

The send function works as i use it elsewhere and it does what it is suppose to.

Comment: `int data 2 = …;`. Syntax error. Zeta.exe has crashed. (That being said, how many characters would a large number need? How many characters can you store in `data3`)?

Comment: Aehm? I don't understand: `int data 2 = ...` how does that even compile?

Comment: Range of `int` is  limited between `−(2^31) to (2^31) − 1`

Comment: sorry miss type it is int data2

Comment: also should have used less numbers for data2, in particular anything past the first 0 in that line will cause the issue

Comment: You should enable all the warnings and debug info in your compiler (e.g. compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. `data2` is overflown by the value to which you have initialized it to.
2. `data3` should be able to hold atleast `11` bytes if `data2` is of int  datatype (+1 for NULL termination), for which you have allocated only 2 bytes.

Here is an example code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long data2 = 12345678910;
    char data3[32];
    snprintf(data3, sizeof(data3), "\"%llu\"", data2);
    printf("%s\n", data3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, `data3` should hold more than 4 characters when `sprintf`-ing an `int`. On my machine you need 10 characters to hold `INT_MAX`; So your example should have a wider `char data3[24];` to avoid truncation.

Comment: Still wrong, the decimal representation of an `int` can take 10 chars. The decimal representation of a `long long` can take 22 chars (at least on my Linux/x86-64 desktop)

Comment: 1) Why use `snprintf()` and not check its result before `printf("%s\n", data3);`  not much safer than using `sprintf()`. 2) `char data3[9];` is too small for `long long`.  Suggest `#define data2N (sizeof data2 * CHAR_BITS)/3+3`  `char data3[data2N];` to right size `char3[]`.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch Minor: suspect your decimal representation of an `int` can take 11 `char` like "-2147483648" + 1 more for the null character.

Answer (score 3):

Before your edit, your issue is not only with `sprintf` (which BTW you should not use, prefer [snprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775403/using-snprintf-to-avoid-buffer-overruns)), it is with integral numbers in C (they have a limited amount of bits, e.g. 64 bits at most on my Linux desktop....; read wikipages on [computer number format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_number_format) & [C data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types)).

Your use of `sprintf` is completely wrong (you've got a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), which is an [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)). You should code:

```
char buffer[32];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%i", data2);
sendsomewhere(buffer);
```

<sup>Notice that on POSIX [send](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/send.html) needs 4 arguments. You should rename your function to `sendsomewhere`</sup>

You should read more about [`<stdint.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html) and [`<limits.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html)

You probably want to use [bignums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) (or at least `int64_t` or perhaps `long long` to represent numbers like 12345678910). Don't reinvent bignums (they are difficult to implement efficiently). Use some library like [gmplib](http://gmplib.org/)

If 64 bits are enough for you (so if your numbers would *always* be between -2<sup>63</sup> i.e. −9223372036854775808 and 2<sup>63</sup>-1 i.e. 9223372036854775807), consider using `long long` (or `unsigned long long`) numbers of [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) or [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29):

```
long long data2 = 12345678910;
char buffer[32];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%lld", data2);
sendsomewhere(buffer);
```

If 64 bits are not enough, you should use [bigint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic)s (but some recent compilers might provide some `_int128_t` type for [128-bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/128-bit) ints)

Don't forget to enable all the warnings & debug info when compiling (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`), then learn how to use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`)